# Unity for iOS plugin not working after renaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I had `LocationController.mm` file in my `Assets/Plugins/iOS` folder. All functionality inside of it worked perfectly. I renamed both file and class inside to `BackgroundController`. After that all functionality stopped working.

As it looks like `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `startUnity` methods never call. If I call `_GetLocation()` method from Unity, it works, but always returns all zeros.

Is there any proper way to import this file? Thank for response.

`BackgroundController.mm` (ex `LocationController.mm`) file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

#import "UnityAppController.h"

@interface BackgroundController : UnityAppController 
<CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@end

extern bool _unityAppReady;

static float latitude = 0;
static float longitude = 0;
static float horizontalAccuracy = 0;

@implementation BackgroundController{
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

-(void) startUnity:(UIApplication*) application {
    [self startStandardUpdates];

    [super startUnity:application];
}

- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; // meters

    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // updating location values
}

// other methods implementation

@end

extern "C" const char* _GetLocation()
{

    NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f",latitude,longitude,horizontalAccuracy];

    char* ret = (char*)::malloc(location.length + 1);
    ::memcpy(ret, [location UTF8String], location.length);
    ret[location.length] = 0;

    return ret;
}

IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(BackgroundController)
```

After build on Xcode file is located in `Libraries/Plugins/iOS` folder as earlier.

I tried to `ReimportAll` files, but that didn't help.

When I rename all back to `LocationController`, still nothing works.

I have all permissions set in `info.plist` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All became work after I renamed file to `BackgroundController.m`, tried to make build, got error and then renamed back to `BackgroundController.mm`.

I did a lot, so I'm not pretty sure if my answer is proper.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53046670/how-to-get-values-from-methods-written-in-ios-plugin-in-unity .                                             Can you help with your code