# How to get values from methods written in IOS plugin in unity?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, plugins, arkit

I am looking to get latitude and longitude values from an IOS plugin.The plugin code is given below which is a .mm file.

```
#import "iPhone_Sensors.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

#include "iPhone_View.h"
#include "iPhone_OrientationSupport.h"

static bool gCompensateSensors = true;
bool gEnableGyroscope = false;
bool IsCompensatingSensors() { return gCompensateSensors; }
void SetCompensatingSensors(bool val) { gCompensateSensors = val;}

void UnityDidAccelerate(float x, float y, float z, NSTimeInterval timestamp);

struct Vector3f
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct Quaternion4f
{
    float x, y, z, w;
};

inline float UnityReorientHeading(float heading)
{
    if (IsCompensatingSensors())
    {
        float rotateBy = 0.f;
        switch (UnityCurrentOrientation())
        {
            case portraitUpsideDown:
                rotateBy = -180.f;
                break;
            case landscapeLeft:
                rotateBy = -270.f;
                break;
            case landscapeRight:
                rotateBy = -90.f;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return fmodf((360.f + heading + rotateBy), 360.f);
    }
    else
    {
        return heading;
    }
}

inline Vector3f UnityReorientVector3(float x, float y, float z)
{
    if (IsCompensatingSensors())
    {
        Vector3f res;
        switch (UnityCurrentOrientation())
        {
            case portraitUpsideDown:
            { res = (Vector3f){-x, -y, z}; }
                break;
            case landscapeLeft:
            { res = (Vector3f){-y, x, z}; }
                break;
            case landscapeRight:
            { res = (Vector3f){y, -x, z}; }
                break;
            default:
            { res = (Vector3f){x, y, z}; }
        }
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        return (Vector3f){x, y, z};
    }
}

static Quaternion4f gQuatRot[4] =
{    // { x*sin(theta/2), y*sin(theta/2), z*sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2) }
    // => { 0, 0, sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2) } (since <vec> = { 0, 0, +/-1})
    { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f /*sin(0)*/, 1.f /*cos(0)*/},    // ROTATION_0, theta = 0 rad
    { 0.f, 0.f, (float)sqrt(2) * 0.5f /*sin(pi/4)*/, -(float)sqrt(2) * 0.5f /*cos(pi/4)*/},    // ROTATION_90, theta = pi/4 rad
    { 0.f, 0.f, 1.f /*sin(pi/2)*/, 0.f /*cos(pi/2)*/},    // ROTATION_180, theta = pi rad
    { 0.f, 0.f, -(float)sqrt(2) * 0.5f/*sin(3pi/4)*/, -(float)sqrt(2) * 0.5f /*cos(3pi/4)*/}    // ROTATION_270, theta = 3pi/2 rad
};

inline void MultQuat(Quaternion4f& result, const Quaternion4f& lhs, const Quaternion4f& rhs)
{
    result.x = lhs.w*rhs.x + lhs.x*rhs.w + lhs.y*rhs.z - lhs.z*rhs.y;
    result.y = lhs.w*rhs.y + lhs.y*rhs.w + lhs.z*rhs.x - lhs.x*rhs.z;
    result.z = lhs.w*rhs.z + lhs.z*rhs.w + lhs.x*rhs.y - lhs.y*rhs.x;
    result.w = lhs.w*rhs.w - lhs.x*rhs.x - lhs.y*rhs.y - lhs.z*rhs.z;
}

inline Quaternion4f UnityReorientQuaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w)
{
    if (IsCompensatingSensors())
    {
        Quaternion4f res, inp = {x, y, z, w};
        switch (UnityCurrentOrientation())
        {
            case landscapeLeft:
                MultQuat(res, inp, gQuatRot[1]);
                break;
            case portraitUpsideDown:
                MultQuat(res, inp, gQuatRot[2]);
                break;
            case landscapeRight:
                MultQuat(res, inp, gQuatRot[3]);
                break;
            default:
                res = inp;
        }
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        return (Quaternion4f){x, y, z, w};
    }
}

void SetGyroRotationRate(int idx, float x, float y, float z);
void SetGyroRotationRateUnbiased(int idx, float x, float y, float z);
void SetGravity(int idx, float x, float y, float z);
void SetUserAcceleration(int idx, float x, float y, float z);
void SetAttitude(int idx, float x, float y, float z, float w);

static CMMotionManager *sMotionManager = nil;
static NSOperationQueue* sMotionQueue = nil;

// Current update interval or 0.0f if not initialized. This is returned
// to the user as current update interval and this value is set to 0.0f when
// gyroscope is disabled.
static float sUpdateInterval = 0.0f;

// Update interval set by the user. Core motion will be set-up to use
// this update interval after disabling and re-enabling gyroscope
// so users can set update interval, disable gyroscope, enable gyroscope and
// after that gyroscope will be updated at this previously set interval.
static float sUserUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 30.0f;

void SensorsCleanup()
{
    if (sMotionManager != nil)
    {
        [sMotionManager stopGyroUpdates];
        [sMotionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
        [sMotionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
        [sMotionManager release];
        sMotionManager = nil;
    }

    if (sMotionQueue != nil)
    {
        [sMotionQueue release];
        sMotionQueue = nil;
    }
}

void CoreMotionStart()
{
    if (sMotionQueue == nil)
        sMotionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    if (sMotionManager == nil)
    {
        sMotionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

        if (sMotionManager.gyroAvailable && gEnableGyroscope)
        {
            [sMotionManager startGyroUpdates];
            [sMotionManager setGyroUpdateInterval: sUpdateInterval];
        }

        if (sMotionManager.deviceMotionAvailable && gEnableGyroscope)
        {
            [sMotionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
            [sMotionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval: sUpdateInterval];
        }

        if (sMotionManager.accelerometerAvailable)
        {
            int frequency = UnityGetAccelerometerFrequency();
            if (frequency > 0)
            {
                [sMotionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue: sMotionQueue withHandler: ^( CMAccelerometerData* data, NSError* error) {
                    Vector3f res = UnityReorientVector3(data.acceleration.x, data.acceleration.y, data.acceleration.z);
                    UnityDidAccelerate(res.x, res.y, res.z, data.timestamp);
                }];
                [sMotionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval: 1.0 / frequency];
            }
        }
    }
}

void CoreMotionStop()
{
    if (sMotionManager != nil)
    {
        [sMotionManager stopGyroUpdates];
        [sMotionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
    }
}

void SetGyroUpdateInterval(int idx, float interval)
{
    if (interval < (1.0f / 60.0f))
        interval = (1.0f / 60.0f);
    else if (interval > (1.0f))
        interval = 1.0f;

    sUserUpdateInterval = interval;

    if (sMotionManager)
    {
        sUpdateInterval = interval;

        [sMotionManager setGyroUpdateInterval: interval];
        [sMotionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval: interval];
    }
}

float GetGyroUpdateInterval(int idx)
{
    return sUpdateInterval;
}

void UpdateGyroData()
{
    CMRotationRate rotationRate = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    CMRotationRate rotationRateUnbiased = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    CMAcceleration userAcceleration = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    CMAcceleration gravity = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    CMQuaternion attitude = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

    if (sMotionManager != nil)
    {
        CMGyroData *gyroData = sMotionManager.gyroData;
        CMDeviceMotion *motionData = sMotionManager.deviceMotion;

        if (gyroData != nil)
        {
            rotationRate = gyroData.rotationRate;
        }

        if (motionData != nil)
        {
            CMAttitude *att = motionData.attitude;

            attitude = att.quaternion;
            rotationRateUnbiased = motionData.rotationRate;
            userAcceleration = motionData.userAcceleration;
            gravity = motionData.gravity;
        }
    }

    Vector3f reorientedRotRate = UnityReorientVector3(rotationRate.x, rotationRate.y, rotationRate.z);
    SetGyroRotationRate(0, reorientedRotRate.x, reorientedRotRate.y, reorientedRotRate.z);

    Vector3f reorientedRotRateUnbiased = UnityReorientVector3(rotationRateUnbiased.x, rotationRateUnbiased.y, rotationRateUnbiased.z);
    SetGyroRotationRateUnbiased(0, reorientedRotRateUnbiased.x, reorientedRotRateUnbiased.y, reorientedRotRateUnbiased.z);

    Vector3f reorientedUserAcc = UnityReorientVector3(userAcceleration.x, userAcceleration.y, userAcceleration.z);
    SetUserAcceleration(0, reorientedUserAcc.x, reorientedUserAcc.y, reorientedUserAcc.z);

    Vector3f reorientedG = UnityReorientVector3(gravity.x, gravity.y, gravity.z);
    SetGravity(0, reorientedG.x, reorientedG.y, reorientedG.z);

    Quaternion4f reorientedAtt = UnityReorientQuaternion(attitude.x, attitude.y, attitude.z, attitude.w);
    SetAttitude(0, reorientedAtt.x, reorientedAtt.y, reorientedAtt.z, reorientedAtt.w);
}

bool IsGyroEnabled(int idx)
{
    if (sMotionManager == nil)
        return false;

    return sMotionManager.gyroAvailable && sMotionManager.gyroActive;
}

bool IsGyroAvailable()
{
    if (sMotionManager != nil)
        return sMotionManager.gyroAvailable;

    return false;
}

@interface LocationServiceDelegate : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end

void
UnitySetLastLocation(double timestamp,
                     float latitude,
                     float longitude,
                     float altitude,
                     float horizontalAccuracy,
                     float verticalAccuracy);

void
UnitySetLastHeading(float magneticHeading,
                    float trueHeading,
                    float rawX, float rawY, float rawZ,
                    double timestamp);

struct LocationServiceInfo
{
private:
    LocationServiceDelegate* delegate;
    CLLocationManager* locationManager;
public:
    LocationServiceStatus locationStatus;
    LocationServiceStatus headingStatus;

    float desiredAccuracy;
    float distanceFilter;

    LocationServiceInfo();
    CLLocationManager* GetLocationManager();
};

LocationServiceInfo::LocationServiceInfo()
{
    locationStatus = kLocationServiceStopped;
    desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    distanceFilter = 500;

    headingStatus = kLocationServiceStopped;
}

static LocationServiceInfo gLocationServiceStatus;

CLLocationManager*
LocationServiceInfo::GetLocationManager()
{
    if (locationManager == nil)
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        delegate = [LocationServiceDelegate alloc];

        locationManager.delegate = delegate;
    }

    return locationManager;
}


bool LocationService::IsServiceEnabledByUser()
{
    return [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
}


void LocationService::SetDesiredAccuracy(float val)
{
    gLocationServiceStatus.desiredAccuracy = val;
}

float LocationService::GetDesiredAccuracy()
{
    return gLocationServiceStatus.desiredAccuracy;
}

void LocationService::SetDistanceFilter(float val)
{
    gLocationServiceStatus.distanceFilter = val;
}

float LocationService::GetDistanceFilter()
{
    return gLocationServiceStatus.distanceFilter;
}

void LocationService::StartUpdatingLocation()
{
    if (gLocationServiceStatus.locationStatus != kLocationServiceRunning)
    {
        CLLocationManager* locationManager = gLocationServiceStatus.GetLocationManager();
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = gLocationServiceStatus.desiredAccuracy;
        // Set a movement threshold for new events
        locationManager.distanceFilter = gLocationServiceStatus.distanceFilter;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        gLocationServiceStatus.locationStatus = kLocationServiceInitializing;
    }
}

void LocationService::StopUpdatingLocation()
{
    if (gLocationServiceStatus.locationStatus == kLocationServiceRunning)
    {
        [gLocationServiceStatus.GetLocationManager() stopUpdatingLocation];
        gLocationServiceStatus.locationStatus = kLocationServiceStopped;
    }
}

void LocationService::SetHeadingUpdatesEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    if (enabled)
    {
        if (gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus != kLocationServiceRunning &&
            IsHeadingAvailable())
        {
            CLLocationManager* locationManager = gLocationServiceStatus.GetLocationManager();

            [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
            gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus = kLocationServiceInitializing;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus == kLocationServiceRunning)
        {
            [gLocationServiceStatus.GetLocationManager() stopUpdatingHeading];
            gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus = kLocationServiceStopped;
        }
    }

}

bool LocationService::IsHeadingUpdatesEnabled()
{
    return (gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus == kLocationServiceRunning);
}

int UnityGetLocationStatus()
{
    return gLocationServiceStatus.locationStatus;
}

int UnityGetHeadingStatus()
{
    return gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus;
}

bool LocationService::IsHeadingAvailable()
{
    return [CLLocationManager headingAvailable];
}

@implementation LocationServiceDelegate

// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    gLocationServiceStatus.locationStatus = kLocationServiceRunning;

    UnitySetLastLocation([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970],
                         newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                         newLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                         newLocation.altitude,
                         newLocation.horizontalAccuracy,
                         newLocation.verticalAccuracy);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus = kLocationServiceRunning;

    Vector3f reorientedRawHeading = UnityReorientVector3(newHeading.x, newHeading.y, newHeading.z);

    UnitySetLastHeading(UnityReorientHeading(newHeading.magneticHeading),
                        UnityReorientHeading(newHeading.trueHeading),
                        reorientedRawHeading.x, reorientedRawHeading.y, reorientedRawHeading.z,
                        [newHeading.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970]);
}

- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager
{
    return NO;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
    gLocationServiceStatus.locationStatus = kLocationServiceFailed;
    gLocationServiceStatus.headingStatus = kLocationServiceFailed;
}

@end
```

I followed this link to extract the required values from the plugin but cant understand how it works.[Plugin into unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

The code below is how I tried to get the latitudes and longitudes from plugin.I wrote a script and added a method

```
    public class Getposition : MonoBehaviour {

#if UNITY_IOS
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
 *********   // Here Which Method should I call?? I am calling from the plugin??
//I have to pass any values?? //*********
    private static extern float UnitySetLastHeading(double timestamp,
                 float latitude,
                 float longitude,
                 float altitude,
                 float horizontalAccuracy,
                 float verticalAccuracy);
#endif

}

public getlatlonginfo( /*what all values required */)
{

//Get values from Plugin??
//string latitudevalues=?
//string longitudevalues=?
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is given below

**Get the values that are picked up in iPhone_Sensors.mm, convert them into a string, and pass them into Unity**

I am trying convert them to string so that I can get more decimal point and thus increase the accuracy.Not that expert with plugins.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I can think of.. First is to use a struct and return the coordinates directly.. The second is to register a callback/handler for when location does update.. You should really take a look at: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Anyway.. some code:

C++ side:

```
//Convert a C++ string to NSString
NSString* CPPStringToIOSString(const char* cppString)
{
    return cppString ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cppString] : nullptr;
}

//Convert an NSString to C++ string.
const char* IOSStringToCPPString(NSString *iosString)
{
    if ([iosString length])
    {
        const char* str = [iosString UTF8String];
        if (str && strlen(str))
        {
            char* unityString = static_cast<char*>(malloc(strlen(str) + 1));
            strcpy(unityString, str);
            return unityString;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}


static LocationServiceInfo GetLocationServiceInfo()
{
    static LocationServiceInfo info;
    return info;
}

//Exports:
extern "C" {

    //When called, returns a CLLocationCoordinate2D to Unity.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _GetCoordinates()
    {
        CLLocationManager *manager = GetLocationServiceInfo().GetLocationManager();
        return [manager getCurrentLocation];
    }

    //When called, registers a listen with LocationManager.
    //The listener is called whenever the location has updated/changed.
    void _RegisterLocationUpdateHandler(void(*callback)(double, double))
    {
        //Implement your own logic for this..
        //Then call `callback` with the lat and lon.
        GetLocationServiceInfo().onLocationDidUpdate = ^(double lat, double lon) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(lat, lon);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

C# side (Plugin)..

```
//Struct representing coordinates received from the iOS plugin.
public struct CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}

//Imported function.
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern CLLocationCoordinate2D _GetCoordinates();

//Call the imported `GetCoordinates` when this function is called.
public static CLLocationCoordinate2D GetCoordinates() 
{
    return _GetCoordinates();
}

//------ Async ------

//Callback function pointer declaration..
public delegate void LocationCallbackFunc(double latitude, double longitude);

 //Imported RegisterLocationUpdate function
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern void _RegisterLocationUpdateHandler(LocationCallback funcPtr);

//This function is called whenever location changed and has been updated via the iOS plugin..
private static void LocationDidChange(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    Debug.Log(latitude);
    Debug.Log(longitude);
}

//Call this function to register the location handler callback to be notified when location changes on the iOS side..
private static void RegisterLocationUpdateHandler()
{
    _RegisterLocationUpdateHandler(new LocationCallbackFunc(this.LocationDidChange))
}
```

Comment: I added the file as .mm file getting a Entrypoint error so it is detecting the plugin but cant find the function name.                                                                                                         
    //Imported function.
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern CLLocationCoordinate2D _GetCoordinates();
    //Call the imported `GetCoordinates` when this function is called.
    public static CLLocationCoordinate2D GetCoordinates()
    {
        return _GetCoordinates();
    }                   I used this in another c# script to get the values

Comment: I just copied the first code and pasted and changed the name to Position.mm

Comment: It should 100% find the `_GetCoordinates` function though. It's exported properly. I tested it in Unity editor.

Comment: Just copy the above plugin and name it New_Pos.mm ,after that should I import any other files?.I added #import "New_Pos.h" and rest the above plugin code. Created a folder 'Plugins' and placed the plugin in that.Then I called the code you provided in my program.The top part of program above you mentioned async I used it my program but Error shows as-----DllNotFoundException: __internal
Getposition.GetCoordinates ()

Comment: Use `[DllImport ("__Internal")]` (with uppercase i): https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

Comment: Now the error ......EntryPointNotFoundException: _GetCoordinates
Getposition.GetCoordinates () (at Assets/Getposition.cs:58)
Getposition.Update () (at Assets/Getposition.cs:107)   ...........................................How to get latitudes and longitudes value .   GetCoordinates().latitude and GetCoordinates().longitude

Comment: Try: https://mega.nz/#!4FEGBYpI!DwcvwUnoRsMoZnHPQ5QvHIblctRVwYlZ7iOqTuS3G7o
I added the code there for my assets folder. You can see that I have a Plugins folder and inside it a Plugin.cs and an iOS folder for iOS specific plugin code.. Otherwise I'm out of ideas because it is working for me :l

Comment: @Brandon.I downloaded your assets.I created a new project copied the assets folder into my assets folder.In Plugin.cs it was showing error for IOSPlugin.So I commented the lines #if UNITY_IOS  and #endif.The error was gone.Next error was in this line private static extern void _RegisterLocationUpdateHandler(LocationCallback funcPtr); so i commented the following lines below async.Now in the Test.cs  I added this line in  Debug.Log("Coordinates Values ="+IOSPlugin.GetCoordinates().ToString()); Getting error EntryPointNotFoundException: _GetCoordinates.

Comment: Pls have a look .The whole unity project I am sending.6Mb file..... 
  
 https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b3ef18d944e4cea6ece26496c52c393920181101051012/2460be

Comment: Confused, In your project UnityIOSCommunicationPlugin.mm is the plugin?public static CLLocationCoordinate2D GetCoordinates() 
 {
  return _GetCoordinates();
 }
How to take coordinates from there?

Comment: It already returns coordinates. You just need to call `GetCoordinates()` and it'll return you a structure that contains latitude and longitude. If you want, you can register a listener and get notified when the user's location changes for live updates as well. I've included it all in that code :)

Comment: What is the use of Plugin.cs.I downloaded and used your project but getting errors.Thts what I cant understand

Comment: You should NOT be getting any errors. The Plugin.cs is a wrapper around IOSPlugin.cs. It abstracts away platform specific stuff.. Notice in `Plugin.cs` I have detection for if running on Android and if running on iOS and stuff. It just does an `#if-def` for Android and iOS.

Comment: @Brandon....I created a newscript and added the following line                 
  void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Coordinates Values ="+IOSPlugin.GetCoordinates().ToString());
        Debug.Log("COOOrdiantes = " + IOSPlugin.GetCoordinates().ToString());
       
    }                      this is the error EntryPointNotFoundException: _GetCoordinates
IOSPlugin.GetCoordinates () (at Assets/Plugins/IOS/IOSPlugin.cs:25)
Test.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Test.cs:18)